# Getting distinct values from object array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : NUUID("f5050a5d-b3be-4de6-a135-a119436fb511"),
    "CoursesData" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Naturgræs",
            "Value" : 1
        }
    ],
    "FacilityType" : {
        "_id" : NUUID("a1b4844b-518b-40e2-8aa5-8ee399ac2d4e")
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve a list with the distinct values from the field `Name` inside my object array of `CourseData`. Filtered by `FacilityType._id`. I tried using both `$facet` and the `distinct` operator, but it doesn't seems to like object arrays.

My result should look like this (or similar):

```
FacilityType (a1b4844b-518b-40e2-8aa5-8ee399ac2d4e),
CourseData: [Name1, Name2, Name3]
```

**Update**

From the answer given below, this is how you do it with the C# driver, if anyone needs to do the same.

```
  FieldDefinition<FacilityDocument, string> field = "CoursesData.Name";

  var result = FacilityCollection.Distinct(field, Builders<FacilityDocument>.Filter.Eq(x => x.FacilityType.ID, new Guid("a1b4844b-518b-40e2-8aa5-8ee399ac2d4e"))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/). It will return distinct element for a specific field from document which match a query

For example if you want distinct value of Name field for facility `"a1b4844b-518b-40e2-8aa5-8ee399ac2d4e"`, run this query:

```
db.collection.distinct("CoursesData.Name", {"FacilityType._id": "a1b4844b-518b-40e2-8aa5-8ee39ac2d4e"})
```

it will return :

```
[ "Naturgræs", ... ]
```

Comment: Thank you felix, i just realized that i misspelled my array when i tried the same distinct option earlier... Hello monday!